# Comparing time periods from frequent repeated measures

Tags: repeated-measures, biostatistics

Simple scenario: We vaccinate animals with two different vaccines (groups A and B, with a negative control C), infect them with the pathogen, and measure many parameters including a daily temperature read for three weeks. Group C spikes a fever on days 1 and 2, then recovers; group A has a smaller fever on day 1, recovers on day 2; group B has no fever on day 1, but has a small rebound fever on day 7.

This is relatively straightforward to compare using a linear mixed model with repeated measures. A key is that we are interested in day-by-day comparisons, because over the three weeks of measurement there are only a couple days of fever, but those are biologically very important.

Now we want to switch our temperature measurement to an implanted chip that logs temperature every five minutes. This is a great improvement in principle because it avoids the risk of catching random temperature fluctuations during the single daily read (in this animal model, handling and stimulation tends to increase temperature somewhat even in normal animals).

Now, how do we compare the temperature curves? Repeated measures still seem to be relevant, but is there a way of blocking off the 288 temperature reads from day 1, day 2, etc so that we can compare each group on a per-day basis?

Better yet, is there a way of identifying the actual start and end of a period of fever, since they won't correlate perfectly with a 24-hour cycle, and comparing those?

Edit: Is it legit to do something like take the "area under the curve" for each time period (e.g. for the 288 samples from day 1, etc) and compare those using repeated measures?